# Encoding AES in Go and Decoding in CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, go, cryptojs

I have these in Go:

```
var commonIV = []byte{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}
plaintext := []byte("hello, world")
key_text := "32o4908go293hohg98fh40gh"
c, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key_text))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: NewCipher(%d bytes) = %s", len(key_text), err)
    return
}
cfbdec := cipher.CBCEncrypter(c, commonIV)
ciphertext := make([]byte, len(plaintext))
cfbdec.CryptBlock(ciphertext, plaintext)
fmt.Printf("%x", ciphertext) //HEX
```

Output:

> e0df84c3b83681a8133e1787

and I import the following urls:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/mode-cfb-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1/build/components/pad-nopadding.js"></script>
```

and my code in JS is the following:

```
var data = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("e0df84c3b83681a8133e1787");
console.log(data);
var key = "32o4908go293hohg98fh40gh";
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==");
console.log(iv);

var encrypted = {};
encrypted.key=key;
encrypted.iv=iv;
encrypted.ciphertext = data;

var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, iv: iv,  padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding  });

console.log(dec);
console.log(dec.toString());
console.log(dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please paste full script of your go code? I run your code and got a panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `CBCEncrypter` (block counter mode) in the Go but `CryptoJS.mode.CFB` (cypher feedback mode) in the JS code.  As far as I know, these are not compatible block modes.

Comment: Thanks I didn't understand the difference in those moments. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want a CBCEncrypter in the Go code?